# Image not showing for a ray-tracer

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, raytracing

I wanted to follow a tutorial posted by Omar Aflak on https://medium.com/swlh/ray-tracing-from-scratch-in-python-41670e6a96f9  but I can’t seem to produce an image? I’m using jupyter notebook if that helps!
This is part of the code that he used, the full one is in the link above!

```
camera = np.array([0, 0, 1])
ratio = float(width) / height
screen = (-1, 1 / ratio, 1, -1 / ratio) # left, top, right, bottom

light = { 'position': np.array([5, 5, 5]), 'ambient': np.array([1, 1, 1]), 'diffuse': np.array([1, 1, 1]), 'specular': np.array([1, 1, 1]) }

objects = [
    { 'center': np.array([-0.2, 0, -1]), 'radius': 0.7, 'ambient': np.array([0.1, 0, 0]), 'diffuse': np.array([0.7, 0, 0]), 'specular': np.array([1, 1, 1]), 'shininess': 100, 'reflection': 0.5 },
    { 'center': np.array([0.1, -0.3, 0]), 'radius': 0.1, 'ambient': np.array([0.1, 0, 0.1]), 'diffuse': np.array([0.7, 0, 0.7]), 'specular': np.array([1, 1, 1]), 'shininess': 100, 'reflection': 0.5 },
    { 'center': np.array([-0.3, 0, 0]), 'radius': 0.15, 'ambient': np.array([0, 0.1, 0]), 'diffuse': np.array([0, 0.6, 0]), 'specular': np.array([1, 1, 1]), 'shininess': 100, 'reflection': 0.5 },
    { 'center': np.array([0, -9000, 0]), 'radius': 9000 - 0.7, 'ambient': np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1]), 'diffuse': np.array([0.6, 0.6, 0.6]), 'specular': np.array([1, 1, 1]), 'shininess': 100, 'reflection': 0.5 }
]

image = np.zeros((height, width, 3))
for i, y in enumerate(np.linspace(screen[1], screen[3], height)):
    for j, x in enumerate(np.linspace(screen[0], screen[2], width)):
        # screen is on origin
        pixel = np.array([x, y, 0])
        origin = camera
        direction = normalize(pixel - origin)

        color = np.zeros((3))
        reflection = 1

        for k in range(max_depth):
            # check for intersections
            nearest_object, min_distance = nearest_intersected_object(objects, origin, direction)
            if nearest_object is None:
                break

            intersection = origin + min_distance * direction
            normal_to_surface = normalize(intersection - nearest_object['center'])
            shifted_point = intersection + 1e-5 * normal_to_surface
            intersection_to_light = normalize(light['position'] - shifted_point)

            _, min_distance = nearest_intersected_object(objects, shifted_point, intersection_to_light)
            intersection_to_light_distance = np.linalg.norm(light['position'] - intersection)
            is_shadowed = min_distance < intersection_to_light_distance

            if is_shadowed:
                break

            illumination = np.zeros((3))

            # ambiant
            illumination += nearest_object['ambient'] * light['ambient']

            # diffuse
            illumination += nearest_object['diffuse'] * light['diffuse'] * np.dot(intersection_to_light, normal_to_surface)

            # specular
            intersection_to_camera = normalize(camera - intersection)
            H = normalize(intersection_to_light + intersection_to_camera)
            illumination += nearest_object['specular'] * light['specular'] * np.dot(normal_to_surface, H) ** (nearest_object['shininess'] / 4)

            # reflection
            color += reflection * illumination
            reflection *= nearest_object['reflection']

            origin = shifted_point
            direction = reflected(direction, normal_to_surface)

        image[i, j] = np.clip(color, 0, 1)
    print("%d/%d" % (i + 1, height))

plt.imsave('image.png', image)
```

Instead of producing an image it just gave me a series of fractions from 1/200 to 200/200…does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Either open the produced "image.png", or use `plt.imshow(image)` to show it in the notebook.

Comment: thank you! do you know how to change the colors of the spheres as well?